# Overriding IAuthSession OnRegistered handler

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack's SocialBootstrapApi and it contains a class CustomUserSession that I can use to override the OnRegistered method. I want to override it because I am attempting to obtain information about the registration so that I can publish an event that a new user has registered. This handler provides an instance of the RegistrationService that handled the registration but not anything about the registration request itself or the resulting UserAuth instance. For instance, I'd like to get the e-mail address used to register.

```
    public override void OnRegistered(IServiceBase registrationService)
    {
        base.OnRegistered(registrationService);

        // Ideally, I could do get the registered user's primary e-mail address from the UserAuth instance.
        var primaryEmail = ((RegistrationService) registrationService)
            .UserAuthRepo
            .GetUserAuth(this, null)  //<--- 'this' is a mostly empty session instance
            .PrimaryEmail;
    }
```

This of course doesn't work because the session instance I'm using for the GetUserAuth call doesn't contain any of the necessary authentication information to be useful for looking up the user's authentication information. So GetUserAuth returns null as you would expect. So how should I go about obtaining this information? Would it be incorrect design for the OnRegistered handler to be passed the UserAuth instance created by the RegistrationService?

```
    public interface IAuthSession
    {
        ...
        void OnRegistered(IServiceBase registrationService, UserAuth userAuth); // <-- new signature
        ...
    }
```

That would be convenient! :)

Or perhaps there's another way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**So how should I go about obtaining this information?**

You should be able to access all the data of the Registration request via the registrationService. You just have to do a little digging and casting...

```
public override void OnRegistered(IServiceBase registrationService)
{
    base.OnRegistered(registrationService);

    var requestContext = (HttpRequestContext)registrationService.RequestContext;
    var dto = ((Registration)requestContext.Dto);
    var primaryEmail = dto.Email;
}
```

**Would it be incorrect design for the OnRegistered handler to be passed the UserAuth instance created by the RegistrationService?**

I'll leave design decisions to the professionals. The above code should work. The casting seems a bit ugly but all the necessary data is there.

I do not like hack into SS, so I chose to select user auth info from UserAuth collection by dto.UserName